redis-search ft.search with json index does not work
How should I search on text field using ft.search when character '@' is present?
I have field with value:

"text": "test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"

but when I am querying like that

ft.search json:search '@text: test*'
data is returned.
But when I am querying like that:
ft.search json:search '@text: *5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d'
no data is returned
also this:
ft.search json:search '@text: test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d'
does not return anything.

Is there a problem with uuid as a TEXT?
How can I escape @? Nothing works here
Read documentation. Experimenting

Have you tried using TAG field? TEXT is meant for full text search, TAG is more suitable for specific string values

FT.CREATE idx ON JSON PREFIX 1 key: SCHEMA $.text AS text TEXT
JSON.SET key:1 $ '{"text": "test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"}'
FT.SEARCH idx '@text:"*com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"' DIALECT 2

"1"
"key:1"


"$"
"{"text":"test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"}"



FT.SEARCH idx '@text:"test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"' DIALECT 2

"1"
"key:1"


"$"
"{"text":"test@gmail.com5d13e891-162a-456b-abf2-fd9b864df96d"}"




It does not work in my environment: (error) Syntax error at offset 7 near com5d13e891

What version of redis stack do you use?

Latest stack image.  Search version 2.10.5

I am using redis/redis-stack-server:latest but the query you wrote doesn't work in my container. Is there some additional configuration I need to do?

I tested it again.  Works as shown.  What result or error are you getting?

Which dialect are you using?
